# Atiyah-sequence-like definition of connection on vector bundles?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

For a principal bundle $\pi: P \to M$ we have the following Atiyah sequence that can be used to define a connection on it
\begin{equation}
  0 \to V{P} \to T{P} \to \pi^*{T{M}} \to 0
\end{equation}
A connection is defined as a $G$-equivariant splitting of the above short exact sequence.

My question is, is there a similar definition (i.e. as a splitting of some short exact sequence) of connections for vector bundles?

Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: Yes. The relevant keyword is "Ehresmann connection". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection#Vector_bundles_and_covariant_derivatives

Comment: Many thanks, Yury!  I think you should post it as an answer to my question to earn more credit!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it helped. I post it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a general notion of a connection, which makes sense for any fiber bundle, namely, Ehresmann connection, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection

In the case of vector bundle $E\to M$, you have to require additionally that for $x\in M$, $e\in E_x$ the splitting of
$$
0 \to Vert_{x,e}\,E\to T_{x,e}E\to \pi^* T_xM\to 0 
$$
 is linear in $e\in E$.